# Pivotal Cloud foundry Access Service from Java App

Tags: cloud-foundry

How would I access credentials from a user provided service bound to a java app.

For example if I create a service like so:

`cf cups <service instance> -p "DB_URL, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD".`

and bind to a java app

In Java Main what would I do to access that service?

```
`  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{ 

    ??????
}`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your Java app, you would access the `VCAP_SERVICES` environment variable.

You can find detailed information here:
http://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-7/services/binding-credentials.html

Answer (score 3):

[Spring Cloud Connectors](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/) can be used to parse the `VCAP_SERVICES` environment variable and provide the credentials in a Java object model. If you format that user-provided service instance credentials in a custom way, then you would need to write some [extension code](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/spring-cloud-connectors.html#_extending_spring_cloud_connectors) to tell Connectors how to parse the credentials.

A better way is to format the service instance credentials in a way that Connectors already understands. The easiest way to do this is usually by providing a single connection string. There are some hints in the [Connectors docs](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/spring-cloud-cloud-foundry-connector.html#_service_detection) showing the credentials formats that Connectors understands for various database types. So you could do something like this:

`cf cups <service instance> -p '{"url", "mysql://username:password@hostname:3306/dbname"}'`

`cf cups <service instance> -p '{"jdbcUrl": "jdbc:mysql://hostname:3306/dbname?user=username&password=password"}'`

or the equivalents for Postgres, Oracle, DB2, or SqlServer.

If you include the [Spring Service Connector](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/spring-cloud-connectors.html#_spring_service_connector) in your project, Connectors will detect the bound service and create the necessary connection objects (e.g. `DataSource`) for you.

Comment: Scott do you have to create different services for each? or can u combine those both together.

Comment: In general, you should create a user-provided service for each external resource your app will connect to.

Comment: do you know the reason why some time my application get stucked on starting stage? 0 of 1 instance.

Comment: I push the same exact code but sometimes it works sometimes it dont.

Comment: I'd have no way of knowing what's going on with your app. Try checking logs with `cf logs app-name --recent`. Make sure you are giving it enough memory - the CF default generally isn't enough for Spring Boot apps.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: How to fill `<service instance>`?