# Cloud Foundry is not picking up Oracle Backing Service

Tags: spring-boot, cloud-foundry

I currently have my database credentials saved as ENV Variables. But I want to change that so the database will be a backing service.

**Env Variables**

```
SPRING_DATASOURCE_driverClassName: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver

//sample url to mask mine
SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:oracle:thin:@//spring.guru.csi0i9rgj9ws.us-east-1.rds.a‌​mazonaws.com:1521/OR‌​C
SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME: UserAdmin
SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD: p4ssw0rd
SPRING_DATASOURCE_initialize: false
```

Script above works and have database connection when running on cloud foundry.

_ _ - _ _ - _ _

Here is the script I input in my command prompt, where I create a service and bound it to my application

```
cf cups OracleTest -p 'username, password, url'
```

[Example Link1](http://docs.pivotal.io/pivotalcf/1-9/devguide/services/user-provided.html)
[Example Link2](http://theblasfrompas.blogspot.com/2014/01/pivotal-cloud-foundry-pcf-binding-user.html)

Once I fill out all the credentials, bind my application to the service, and restage my application. I do not receive any database connection.

**My Attempt on CF**

[image: Example]

```
//for uri I also tried 
jdbc:oracle:thin:@//spring.guru.csi0i9rgj9ws.us-east-1.rds.a‌​mazonaws.com:1521/OR‌​C
```

--Do I need some java configuartions along with this?

Answer (score 0):

I did a quick search. I couldn't find an example where you can set the drivername in the CUPS service. You may try removing it from the CUPS definition.

Here is another way of setting the CUPs service -  [Pivotal Cloud foundry Access Service from Java App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37715329/pivotal-cloud-foundry-access-service-from-java-app)

Give it a try

Comment: The Spring Cloud Connectors and user-provided service approach described in my answer to that question will work with Oracle databases as long as you provide a URL that follows the conventions in the Connectors documentation: http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-connectors/spring-cloud-cloud-foundry-connector.html#_oracle.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the unnecessary parameters and used the follow

```
cf cups OracleDB -p '{"jdbcUrl":"jdbc:oracle:thin:[username]/[password]@//[host]:[port]/[service]"}'
```

So instead of adding each attribute one by one. I found out that it can accept one of the following.

```
Oracle
The connector will check for:

uri or uris using the scheme oracle

jdbcUrl field in credentials using the scheme oracle

oracleUri, oracleuri, oracleUrl, or oracleurl fields in credentials
```

I choose jdbc and added credentials in the url.